# Define colours for three categories of a subset

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have come to a point in my R script where I did not yet succeed in finding a solution and hope you can help me. My English might be a bit awkward as I'm not a native speaker, so please bear with me. ;-)

What I did so far..
I sampled a lot of individuals and plotted the growth curve for this species with following command:

```
 plot(mydata$Weight, mydata$SVL, ylab="SVL (mm)", xlab="Body mass (g)",
 col=mydata$Sex, pch=19, cex=0.65)
```

I used col=mydata$Sex to assign different colours to females, males and juveniles. It all went well and I received a nice curve with "red", "green" and "black" dots.

The thing is, that all my other related graphs are in "blue", "red" and "black". Therefore, I would like to adjust the "green" to "blue" (not that I don't like green, but thinking of people with daltonism I prefer to not publish red and green graphs). I know that for two colours I could use

```
 col=ifelse(mydata§Sex==F, "red","black"),
```

but it seems not to work for three colours.

Any ideas anybody?

Cheers,

Userphine

Comment: I find this approach easier `col = c('red','black')[factor(Sex)]` such that each color in the vector is matched 1-1 with `levels(sex)` and you can use any number of colors

Comment: I had to use [factor(mydata$Sex)], but it works and I can adjust the colours the way I really want them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ifelse` you can fix it this way:

```
col=ifelse(mydata$Sex=="M",4,mydata$Sex)
```

Comment: This also works well and I could change exactly the colour I wanted to. For adjusting several colours the answer given by rawr is easier, but it's always good to know more than one way to do things. Thanks to you as well.